# Jquery New Element Doesn't Receive Value

Tags: jquery

I am adding new elements to the DOM using a utility function which is contained below.

```
HtmlCore.prototype.createElement = function(tag, attrs, css, value){
    return $("<" + tag + ">", attrs).css(css).val(value);
};
```

For some reason the new element doesn't receive the value, when I append it to the DOM.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set value only to input elements. If you are trying to set the values for non input elements then it will not work.

Comment: Thanks for ending my end of the day brain malfunction. I was trying to set the value of a label